# How to perform another UIViewController above an UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have tried to call [alertController presentViewController:anotherVC animated:YES]. It works, but not well. The buttons in anotherVC are in grey colour, although they can still handle clicks. And, after dismissing anotherVC, alertController is not shown correctly. It is shown at the top of the screen, and some part of it is beyond the screen.

So, is there any good way to present another UIViewController above an UIAlertController?

Comment: Can you please attach SCreen Shot ?

Comment: UIAlertController perform in Main Thread, so may be its not possible. you have to design custom Alert View for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is easily doable. You could create a second window with window level `UIWindowLevelAlert` and show your top most view controller in there, but having multiple windows is hard to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

AlertView Controller Hierarchy is top of the window so  its not possible to do this with default alertViewController .

**Solution :** you can create Custom alert view and handle it as you want .(easiest way)